# Kotlin/MP: Create a second JS library build from commonMain for use by web Worker?

Tags: javascript, angular, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a Kotlin/Multiplatform build supporting a backend server (java) and an Angular app (ts/js).  Code in `commonMain` builds for both targets and I'm using it on both sides with no troubles.

It even makes use of a Kotlin/MP sub-module library named "melange".

*build.gradle.kts:* (abridged)

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.8.10"
    id("com.github.node-gradle.node") version "3.5.+"
    application
}

kotlin {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.8.10"
    val kotlinxHtmlVersion = "0.8.+"
    val ktorVersion = "2.2.+"

    js(IR) {
        binaries.executable()
        compilations.all {}
        browser {}
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(project(":modules:melange"))
            }
        }

        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                ...
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting

        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                ...
            }
        }
        val jsTest by getting
    }
}
...
```

Now I'm trying to add a web `Worker()` thread to my Angular app.  I've created a template `my.worker.ts` file and successfully launched it.  I know that I can't access from the worker all the library code that was loaded as part of the main app but I need to access a couple of classes from `commonMain`.  Importing those classes the same way as the app does causes a complete duplication of the library (some 400KiB).

*How can I include only the classes required by my web worker instead of the full "common" build?*

I can think of two general solutions:

1. Have a separate library build target in Gradle that includes only those classes that are necessary.
2. Run dead-code elimination on the generated .js file that removes everything other than what is actually used.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any good answers on how to do either of these.

Comment: how about moving those classes into a new KMP library (A) and make this existing KMP library (B) depend on (A) and then use js export of (A) in your worker code.

That would be one way to do this cleanly as you can create new library (A) which would have a specific domain, or you can also call it (core) library and existing one as specific domain library.

Having a new KMP module in the existing repo structure won't be a huge overhead.

Comment: Possible, but that sub-libraries add a significant amount of complication to the layout, source control, and build system.  Seems a lot of overhead for just one or two classes.  Worth keeping in mind, though.